# asp.net web app, embedded resource not found after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, embedded-resource

As explained in title, this sounds very simple, though, I have not been able to make it work or to understand why by my researches.

Simple scenario : 
I create a web app in ASP.NET.
I create my App_GlobalResources foledr, with some Resource.resx, set with a Build 'Embedded'
When I publish and try the web app : [Parser Error]  The resource object with key 'Msg1' was not found.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't get any responses and I was facing the same trouble, I feel like I should answer you.
The solution is very simple, after you did the Publish Web Application, you only need to right click the "App_GlobalResources"(in my case) and select "Publish App_GlobalResources", that will copy the .resx files into the root and it should work!